# Throttle observable based on whether handler is still busy

Tags: system.reactive, throttling

I have an `IObservable` that generates a value every second, followed by a select that runs some code that may take some time:

```
var events = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
ssoInfoObservable = events
    .Select(e =>
    {
        // ... perform long-running operation ...
    })
```

The long-running operation may take more than one second so the first question is: will Rx push a new event even though handling of the previous hasn't finished yet? I suppose it will.

Second question is: how can I skip events while a previous event is still being handled?

Comment: Please see [Whats a good way to run periodic tasks in c# using Rx with a single concurrent execution restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31400259/638167) which seems pretty much what you need

Comment: Ah, seems this already works as I want it to :) That's nice. Thanks! I should mark this as a duplicate I guess :)

Comment: The key thing to understand is that `Observable.Interval` is pretty much an "interval" timer - it specifies the interval (gap) between the processing of two values, not between starting points.