# Throttle IObservable based on whether async handler is still busy

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive, throttling

I have an `IObservable` that generates a value every second, followed by a select that runs code that may take some time:

```
var events = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
ssoInfoObservable = events
    .Select(async e =>
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Select   : " + e);
        await Task.Delay(4000);
        return e;
    })
    .SelectMany(t => t.ToObservable())
    .Subscribe(l => Console.WriteLine("Subscribe: " + l));
```

The long-running operation takes 4 seconds in my example. While the code inside `Select` is running, I do not want another value from the `Interval` to be generated. How do I accomplish this? Is this possible? Maybe use a specific `IScheduler` implementation?

Note that if there's no async code, everything works as expected as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457743/throttle-observable-based-on-whether-handler-is-still-busy).

This question is very similar to [one I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457743/throttle-observable-based-on-whether-handler-is-still-busy), except for the `async/await`.

Comment: The `.ObserveOn(...)` doesn't make a difference. The `.Interval(...)` operator times the gap (i.e. interval) between each set of handlers and not between each start time.

Comment: I see that I have made my example code too simple, I have updated my question to reflect my actual code.

Comment: This is still limited by the number of threads that actually run. I only every got four selects ahead and then it just stayed there. I'll have a think, but can you describe why this is your actual code? What problem do you think it solves for you?

Comment: The most important requirement is that the `Select` doesn't run in parallel. The operation that's awaited can be long-running (waiting for a result to become available in a db) and produces the result for the rest of the chain. The simple solution would of course be to synchronously wait for the `Result` of the awaited task. Actual code is quite similar, except I await something useful.

Comment: Why are you mixing Observables as `await` like this? Observables achieve the purpose of pushing your work to a background thread thus freeing up the UI (or main thread) to be responsive for other code. Mixing in `await` is kind of like "double-dipping".

Comment: Rx naturally ensure the `Select` will run is series if you don't introduce concurrency.

Comment: I guess you're right :) Was wondering the same thing after giving it some more thought.The reason for using the `await` is simply that the API I'm calling only offers async methods. So I naturally started with `await`, discovered the undesired behavior and tried to find a solution. I'm now going to wait for the result synchronously. It's more an academic excercise now to try and find a solution that allows the use of `await` (without using global state because that would be too easy :)

Comment: I think you need to introduce some sort of state. Rx does a nice job of **not** multi-threading unless you construct your query to introduce it. But once you have it is much harder to remove it the concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

See this sample on creating an [async generate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31486750/2521865). Your would be slightly different in that you need a time offset and you don't need the `iterate` so it would look more like this:

```
    public static IObservable<T> GenerateAsync<T>(TimeSpan span, 
                                                  Func<int, Task<T>> generator, 
                                                  IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        scheduler = scheduler ?? Scheduler.Default;

        return Observable.Create<T>(obs =>
        {
            return scheduler.Schedule(0, span, async (idx, recurse) =>
            {
                obs.OnNext(await generator(idx));
                recurse(idx + 1, span);
            });

        });
    }
```

Usage:

```
  Extensions.GenerateAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), idx => /*Async work, return a task*/, scheduler);
```

As a possible second option you could look to port the implementation of [`switchFirst`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/switchfirst.js) into C#. `SwitchFirst` will subscribe to the first Observable it receives and ignore subsequent ones until its current subscription completes.

If you took that approach you could have something like:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
          .Select(e => Observable.FromAsync(() => /*Do Async stuff*/)
          .SwitchFirst()
          .Subscribe();
```