# Run periodic tasks using Rx.net: cancel and stop Observale.Interval stream after N seconds?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, cancellationtokensource, rx.net

In the following code from the answer of [What's a good way to run periodic tasks using Rx, with a single concurrent execution restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399054/whats-a-good-way-to-run-periodic-tasks-using-rx-with-a-single-concurrent-execu/31400259#31400259),

```
void Main()
{
    var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    using (timer.Do(x => Console.WriteLine("!")).Subscribe(tick => DoSomething()))
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    Console.Write("<");
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(">");
}
```

I'm trying to add `cancellation` and test stopping the program after five seconds.

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;

Task DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken=default)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { return Task.CompletedTask;  }
    Console.Write("<");
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(">");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

async Task WaitAndThenCancel(int seconds, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
    await Task.Delay(seconds*1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Cancelling...");
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}

void Main(CancellationToken cancellationToken=default)
{
    var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    using (timer. Do(x =>
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Canceled - Main");
            return; // Need to stop the stream here
        }
        Console.WriteLine("!");
    }).Subscribe(async tick => await DoSomething(cancellationToken)))
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

var ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
WaitAndThenCancel(5, ct);
Main(ct.Token);
```

I expect the code to print the current time for N seconds, and then print "Canceled - Main" and stop. However, it starts to print "Canceled - Main" after N seconds and never stop?

```
!
<15:00:23.823>
!
<15:00:24.836>
!
<15:00:25.853>
!
<15:00:26.860>
!
<15:00:27.863Cancelling...
>
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
Canceled - Main
....
```

[image: To support async DoSomething()]

Using `TakeUntil()`.

```
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return; // Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    Console.Write("<");
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
    await Task.Delay(1000); // Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(">");
}

async Task Main3(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    var cancel = Observable.Create<Unit>(observer => cancellationToken.Register(() => { 
        // observer.OnNext(default); 
        observer.OnCompleted(); }));
    using (timer.Do(x =>
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Canceled - Main");
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("do!");
            })
            .TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)))
            .TakeUntil(cancel)
            .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomething(cancellationToken)))
            .Concat()
            .Subscribe())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Will wait for timed cancelation here.");
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($">{Environment.NewLine}Canceled - Main. In Using");
        }
    }
}

var ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
ct.CancelAfter(5000);
await Main3(ct.Token);
```

Comment: you are mixing RX with Task, I assumed that is dure to low experience? treat yur observales as unit. await myMainObseervalbe.TakeUntil(emitAfter5Seconds)

Comment: I'm new to Rx, the `Wait()` is for testing cancellation - it cancels the process after 5 seconds by setting the variable.

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris, the question is updated. there were some issues in the old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run an observable and stop it after a set time interval then you should simply use `.TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)))`.

```
var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

var subscription =
    timer
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("!"))
        .TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)))
        .Subscribe(tick => DoSomething());
        
using (subscription)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you want to use a `CancellationToken` then you could use this:

```
var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
var cancel = Observable.Create<Unit>(observer => cts.Token.Register(() => { observer.OnNext(default); observer.OnCompleted(); }));

var subscription =
    timer
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine("!"))
        .TakeUntil(cancel)
        .Subscribe(tick => DoSomething());
        
using (subscription)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0));
    cts.Cancel();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Can I do both `.TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)))` and using `cancellationToken`? Using two `TakeUntil()`?

Comment: @ca9163d9 - You can try and find out. These fluent interfaces are pretty cool.

Comment: Curiously, in `Observable.Create<Unit>(observer => cts.Token.Register(() => { observer.OnNext(default); observer.OnCompleted(); }));`, why we need `observer.OnNext(default);`? I tried to remove it and it works too?

Comment: @ca9163d9 - It didn't work for me. You must have the `OnNext`. Can you show me code where it worked for you?

Comment: I've posted the code screenshot at the end of the question.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - Please don't post screenshots. Please post the actual code so I can run it.

Comment: OK. Posted the code.

Comment: Your `await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);` is dropped out when you cancel the token and thus unsubscribing. The `cancel` observable isn't being hit at all.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - Sorry, forgot to `@` you.

Comment: It did print the line thought `Console.WriteLine($">{Environment.NewLine}Canceled - Main. In Using");`.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - Yes, because the `await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);` was cancelled.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - If you comment out the `.TakeUntil(cancel)` line it still cancels the same way. You're just calling `Dispose` on the subscription.

Comment: I added `Console.ReadLine();` at the end, and if I comment out `.TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)))` (so only `TakeUntil(cancel)`, it will keep printing `Canceled - Main` after five seconds - with or without `observer.OnNext(default);`.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - I made the changes to the code you described. When I include `observer.OnNext(default);` the observable stops. When I comment it out it goes on forever.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Main` is not canceling subscription because `Console.ReadLine();` prevents it from doing so. I suggest a slightly different approach:

```
async Task Main(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    using (timer.Do(x =>
           {
               if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Canceled - Main");
                   return;
               }
               Console.WriteLine("!");
           }).Subscribe(async tick => await DoSomething(cancellationToken)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Will wait for timed cancelation here.");
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($">{Environment.NewLine}Canceled - Main. In Using");
        }
    }
}

var ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
ct.CancelAfter(5000); // also no need to reinvent the wheel, just use the build in method for timed cancelation 
await Main(ct.Token);
```

One more note `Subscribe` is not task-aware, i.e. it will not handle "truly" async methods correctly. For example if you change the `DoSomething` method to the following:

```cs
async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }

    Console.Write("<");
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(">");
}
```

The result will differ from what is expected/wanted. One approach to handle that is:

```
using (timer.Do(x =>
           {
               if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Canceled - Main");
                   return;
               }

               Console.WriteLine("!");
           })
           .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomething(cancellationToken)))
           .Concat()
           .Subscribe())
{
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the last piece of the code is similar to another high voted answers in the original question I referred. Is it the better approach? I couldn't make it work in my test console program (it didn't print anything). Will try it again.

Comment: I tried to run `using (timer.Do(x => {....}).Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomething(cancellationToken))).Concat().Subscribe()){}`, but it didn't print anything.

Comment: @ca9163d9 my answer contains full runnable code which I've used for testing (except for original `DoSomething` implmentation).

Comment: hmm, I've posted the full source code screenshot in the question.

Comment: @ca9163d9 yep, that misses some crucial parts from my code. i.e. `await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);` and `async` for `Main`. Without it the `Dispose` called by `using` will cancel subscription immediately (`Console.ReadLine();` served the similar purpose in the original code).

Comment: It works after I added the missing part. However, I found that removing `if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }` in `timer.Do(x => { ... }` also works. Is it needed?

Comment: @ca9163d9 I would say - no, to my understanding it was added for testing purposes.