# Partition an observable stream of IEnumerable<T> with a delay in Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following Rx extension method for partitioning an `IEnumerable<T>` and delaying the producing of each partitioned value. It uses an `IEnumerable<T>` extension to partition the data, which is also shown with a unit test.

Is there a better way to do the 'delay' than using the `Observable.Timer().Wait()` method call?

```
public static class RxExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> PartitionWithInterval<T>(
        this IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> source, int size, TimeSpan interval,
        IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        if (scheduler == null)
        {
            scheduler = TaskPoolScheduler.Default;
        }

        var intervalEnabled = false;
        return source.SelectMany(x => x.Partition(size).ToObservable())
            .Window(1)
            .SelectMany(x =>
            {
                if (!intervalEnabled)
                {
                    intervalEnabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Observable.Timer(interval, TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Wait();
                }

                return x;
            })
            .ObserveOn(scheduler);
    } 
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
    {
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var items = new List<T>();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                items.Add(enumerator.Current);
                if (items.Count == size)
                {
                    yield return items.ToArray();

                    items.Clear();
                }
            }
           
            if (items.Any())
            {
                yield return items.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test for the Rx extension method is shown below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     try
     {
         var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
         var interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

         Observable.Return(data)
            .PartitionWithInterval(2, interval)
            .Timestamp()
            .Subscribe(x =>
                {
                   var message = $"{x.Timestamp} - count = {x.Value.Count()}" +
                       $", values - {x.Value.First()}, {x.Value.Last()}";
                   Console.WriteLine(message);
                });

           Console.ReadLine();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(e);
       }
}
```

Comment: *"I have the following Rx extension method for partitioning an IEnumerable<T>"* <== Does this literaly mean that you have a single `IEnumerable<T>` to partition? I.e. is the `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>` expected to emit a single `IEnumerable<T>`, and then complete?

Comment: Related: [Reactive Extensions: Process events in batches + add delay between every batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927298/reactive-extensions-process-events-in-batches-add-delay-between-every-batch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> PartitionWithInterval<T>(this IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> source, int size, TimeSpan interval, IScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    if (scheduler == null)
    {
        scheduler = TaskPoolScheduler.Default;
    }

    return source
        //don't need the .ToObservable() call, since Zip can work on IEnumerable + IObservable.
        .SelectMany(x => x.Partition(size)) 
        .Zip(Observable.Interval(interval, scheduler).StartWith(0), (x, _) => x)
        .ObserveOn(scheduler);
}
```

Funny how `PartitionWithInterval` actually calls `Partition` and `Interval`.

The `StartWith` is just there so you get a partition dropped immediately: Similar to how you had the `intervalEnabled` flag.

Comment: The Rx `Zip` operator is scary. It buffers the values coming from the faster of the two observables, resulting potentially to massive memory allocation during a long-life subscription.

Comment: In this case the faster observable is actually an enumerable, so the values are already in memory.

Comment: Hmm. Is the `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> source` supposed to emit a single `IEnumerable<T>`, that should also be emitted synchronously during the subscription? If so, you are right about the `Zip`, but you should probably enforce this requirement somehow. The single emission requirement could be enforced by the `SingleAsync` operator, but the synchronous emission requirement how?

Comment: It’s in the question. You start with an enumerable [012345789], and get an observable that time-spaces out the enumerable in clumps: [01]...[23]...[45]... The faster source here is the enumerable (which again, is already in memory).

Comment: This seems to be just a test for validating the correctness of the `PartitionWithInterval` method. I don't think that this test indicates how the OP intends to use this method in practice.

Comment: First sentence: "I have the following Rx extension method for partitioning an IEnumerable<T> and delaying the producing of each partitioned value"

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. I asked the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: Even in case that the OP's intention is to partition a singe `IEnumerable<T>`, enumerating it eagerly and storing all its values into memory seems like a bad idea. An `IEnumerable<T>` can potentially emit an infinite number of values. A more efficient approach would be to enumerate it lazily on every `interval`, just enough to produce a partition and emit it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of the `PartitionWithInterval` operator, that is optimized towards memory efficiency. The enumerables emitted by the `IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>` are enumerated lazily, just enough to produce the next one or two partitions. Then their enumeration is suspended until the next interval. To achieve this laziness, the implementation uses `IAsyncEnumerable`s instead of `IObservable`s, and makes use of operators from the packages [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) and [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async).

```
public static IObservable<IList<T>> PartitionWithInterval<T>(
    this IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> source, int size,
    TimeSpan interval, IScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    scheduler ??= Scheduler.Default;
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        Task delayTask = Task.CompletedTask;
        return source
            .ToAsyncEnumerable()
            .SelectMany(x => x.ToAsyncEnumerable()).Buffer(size) /* Behavior A */
            //.SelectMany(x => x.ToAsyncEnumerable().Buffer(size)) /* Behavior B */
            .Do(async (_, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                await delayTask;
                var timer = Observable.Timer(interval, scheduler);
                delayTask = timer.ToTask(cancellationToken);
            })
            .ToObservable();
    });
}
```

Below is a marble diagram that shows the behavior of the `PartitionWithInterval` operator, configured with `size: 2`:

```xml
Source: +----[1,2,3,4,5]--------------------[6,7,8,9]---|
Output: +----[1,2]-------[3,4]--------------[5,6]-------[7,8]-------[9]|
```

As shown, an output partition may contain values from more than one enumerables (the partition `[5,6]` in the above diagram). In case this is undesirable, just comment the line "Behavior A" and uncomment the line "Behavior B". The marble diagram below shows the effect of this change:

```xml
Source: +----[1,2,3,4,5]--------------------[6,7,8,9]---|
Output: +----[1,2]-------[3,4]-------[5]-------[6,7]-------[8,9]|
```

---

**Note:** The above solution is not absolutely satisfactory regarding the intention to enumerate lazily the enumerables emitted by the source observable. The ideal would be to produce each partition exactly at the time it should be emitted. Instead, the above implementation gathers the elements of the next partition immediately after emitting the previous partition. The alternative would be to enforce a delay after emitting each partition, including the last one. This would postpone the completion of the resulting `IObservable` by a  time span equal to `interval`, which is not ideal either (this behavior is implemented by the [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65640081/3) of this answer). The ideal behavior could probably be achieved by re-implementing the operators `ToAsyncEnumerable`, `SelectMany`, `Buffer` and `Do`, so that they communicate the state `IsLast` of the currently emitted element. Even if this is possible, it would require a lot of effort for such a measly improvement.

Answer (score -1):

Feels like you have to use operator [Buffer](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Buffer). Try this:

```
            data.ToObservable()
                .Buffer(2)
                .Zip(Observable.Interval(interval), (x, _) => x)
                .Timestamp()
                .Subscribe(x =>
                    {
                        var message = $"buffer {x.Timestamp} - count = {x.Value.Count()}, values - {x.Value.First()}, {x.Value.Last()}";
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                    });
```